# How do I get rid of the error message "cannot implicitly type CLASSLibrary(classname) to ClassLibrary.(classname)

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to get rid of this error to save my life. The main goal of my assignment is as soon as the user hits the submit button it should filter out the user "employee class" from a drop down menu and spit out X result. My issue I'm running into is an error message stating "cannot implicitly convert type 'csis265.domain(className) to csis265.employee"

Main ClassLibrary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using log4net;

namespace csis265.domain
{
    public abstract class employee
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
                log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        protected string firstName;
        protected string lastName;
        protected double payRate;
        protected double hoursWorked;

        public employee() : this("", "", 0.0, 0.0)
        {

        }

        public employee(string firstName, string lastName, double payRate, double hoursWorked)
        {
            setfirstName(firstName);
            setlastName(lastName);
            setpayRate(payRate);
            sethoursWorked(hoursWorked);
        }

        public void setfirstName(string firstName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public void setlastName(string lastName)
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public void setpayRate(double payRate)
        {
            this.payRate = payRate;
        }

        public void sethoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
        {
            this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        }

        //GETTERS

        public string getfirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public string getlastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        public double getpayRate()
        {
            return payRate;
        }

        public double gethoursWorked()
        {
            return hoursWorked;
        }



        public abstract double GetWeeklyPay();
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Format("EMP: FN: {0} LN: {1} PR: {2} HW: {3}",
                firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked);
            return output;
        }

        public virtual void Display()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Employee.ASPX

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using log4net;
using csis265.domain;


namespace csis265proj05
{
    public partial class employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
                log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                logger.Debug("Web page is being posted back");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Debug("first time entering");
            }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Debug("user clicked submit");

            string firstName = "";
            string lastName = "";
            double payRate = 0.0;
            double hoursWorked = 0.0;
            double bonus = 0.0;
            string type = string.Empty;
            employee emp = null;
            type = DropEmpl.SelectedValue;

            try
            {
                lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;

                firstName = Convert.ToString(txtFirst.Text);
                lastName = Convert.ToString(txtLast.Text);
                payRate = Convert.ToDouble(txtPay.Text);
                hoursWorked = Convert.ToDouble(TxtHours.Text);


                if (type.ToLower().Equals("wage employee"))
                {
                    emp = new wageemployee(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked);
                }

                if (type.ToLower().Equals("salary employee"))
                {
                    emp = new salaryemployee(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked);
                }

                if (type.ToLower().Equals("exectuive employee"))
                {
                    bonus = Convert.ToDouble(TxtBonus.Text);
                    emp = new executiveemployee(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked, bonus);
                }

                lblMessage.Text = emp.ToString();
                logger.Debug(emp.ToString());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
                lblMessage.Text = "Please enter valid data";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implemented Classes

sal emp

```
namespace csis265.domain
{
   public class salaryemployee : employee 
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        public salaryemployee(): this("", "", 0.0, 0.0)
        {

        }

        public salaryemployee(string firstName, string lastName, double payRate, double hoursWorked)
            :base(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.payRate = payRate;
            this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        }

        public override double GetWeeklyPay()
        {
            return payRate/52;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Format("FN: {0} LN: {1} PR: {2} HW: {3} WKPay: {4}",
                firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked, GetWeeklyPay());
            return output;
        }
```

exec

```
namespace csis265.domain
{
    public class executiveemployee : employee
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        protected double bonus;

        public executiveemployee() : this("", "", 0.0, 0.0,0.0)
        {

        }

        public executiveemployee(string firstName, string lastName, double payRate, double hoursWorked, double bonus)
            : base(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked)
        {
            setBonus(bonus);
        }

        public void setBonus(double bonus)
        {
            this.bonus = bonus;
        }

        public double getBonus()
        {
            return bonus;
        }

        public override double GetWeeklyPay()
        {
            return payRate * hoursWorked;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Format("FN: {0} LN: {1} PR: {2} HW: {3} BN: {4} WKPay: {5}",
                firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked, bonus, GetWeeklyPay());
            return output;
        }
```

wage emp

```
namespace csis265.domain
{
    public class wageemployee : employee
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger =
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        protected double bonus;

        public wageemployee() : this("", "", 0.0, 0.0)
        {

        }

        public wageemployee(string firstName, string lastName, double payRate, double hoursWorked)
            : base(firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.payRate = payRate;
            this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        }

        public override double GetWeeklyPay()
        { 
            return (payRate + bonus) * hoursWorked;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Format("FN: {0} LN: {1} PR: {2} HW: {3} WKPay: {4}",
                firstName, lastName, payRate, hoursWorked, GetWeeklyPay());
            return output;
        }

        public new void Display()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the implementation for `wageemployee`, `salaryemployee`, and  `executiveemployee`?

Comment: Not a good idea to have two totally unrelated classes with the same name. The Page _employee_ and the abstract class _employee_. To add some salt to the confusion the page class is partial. Can you change the name of your page class?

Comment: @P.N. I just did, sorry about that. They all reference the main employee class

Comment: @MinhPhan I've edited my answer, not sure if you were notified

Answer (score 0):

Do the wageemployee, salaryemployee and executiveemployee classes implement the employee class?

I'm guessing one of them doesn't.

Like: `public class wageemployee : employee`

**EDIT**

Yup, they do.

Then perhaps the `employee` object at this line `employee emp = null;` in Employee.aspx, references to `csis265proj05.employee` instead of `csis265.domain.employee`?